# In a predictive model, is orthogonality of noise and predictors an assumption or something that can be proved?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

Consider the general problem of predicting the conditional mean $E(Y|X)$ where $X$ is the predictor. One assumes $Y$ can be written as:

$Y=f(x)+e$ where $E(e|X)=0$ which implies covariance of predictor and $e$ is 0. Is $E(e|X)=0$ an assumption that is made or is it something that follows automatically from the fact that $f$ is the conditional mean of $Y$ (conditioned on $X$)?

If it's an assumption, what drives us to make it?

Comment: I can't figure out what your "$x$" refers to: I'll assume it means "$X.$" You seem to be asking that if $f(X)= E[Y\mid X] = E[f(X)+e\mid X],$ then can we conclude $E[e\mid X] = 0$?  If so, then look up *linearity of expectation* and *taking out what is known.*  As far as "what drives us," could you tell us what kind of alternative you are contemplating?

Comment: Understood, thanks! I was trying to split conceptually a conditional expectation and causality in my head. They are not the same thing is what I concluded.